# How to call youtube api in Firebase Function Spark mode

Tags: node.js, firebase, youtube-api, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase for first time. I manage Firebase to store the data in database and send external http rquest not working.

I am calling Youtube api to get data. I am reading many answers here saying only google owned api are allowed. My code doesn't work on sending request to youtube api.

Someone please check and help.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var req = require('request');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var db = admin.firestore();

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=id,snippet,replies&allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=abcd&maxResults=100&order=time&key=key"
    req(url, function (error, resp, body) {
        if (!error && resp.statusCode === 200) {
            return resp;
            // var comments = JSON.parse(body);
            // comments.forEach(comment => {
            //     var dataid = com.snippet.topLevelComment.id;
            //     var docRef = db.collection("comments").doc(dataid);
            //     var storeInDB = docRef.set(comment);
            // });
        }
    });
    response.send("hello World");
});
```

This function does work fine when I just return the response so I think, Youtbe api thing work fine, But when I uncomment the code which does parse the response and trying to store it in database I see this

[image]

Function execution started
6:46:31.736 PM
outlined_flag
helloWorld
Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
6:46:31.829 PM
outlined_flag
helloWorld
Function execution took 94 ms, finished with status code: 200

Comment: Please edit your question to show exactly what doesn't work as you expect.  Are there errors?  In the logs maybe?

Comment: @DougStevenson I just see the response when I simply return it, it does failed when I uncomment my 4 line code. So youtube request sending part work but somehow it failed at database part.

Answer (score 1):

In Spark mode, you won't be able to make a call to YouTube API since it isn't supported.

Firebase still thinks that you are calling external API which requires billing setup.

Use Blaze plan which is pay as you go. It feels like the most expensive plan since it is located in the far right. Yet, it includes free tier quota. Once it goes over then you will be charged. You can set low budget to cap it. Then it becomes basically same free tier with billing setup.

Comment: Please check my comment on Question, I got the response but code is not able to parse json